# TensorContract and TensorProduct problem

Tags: tensors

I am trying the calculate the Kretschmann scalar $K$ of a metric $$K=R^{abcd}R_{abcd}$$ where $R$ is the Riemann tensor. If I do

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[R,R],{{1,5},{2,6},{3,7},{4,8}}]
```

I get a scalar function, but is this code equivalent to the above formula? Should I raise the indices of the first Riemann tensor with the inverse of the metric, or does Mathematica do this for me? Even if the metric is pseudo-Riemannian and with complicated coefficients?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematica contracts indices assuming flat Euclidean metric. You have to lower/raise the indices yourself.

```
g = DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1, -1, -1}];

RaiseIndex[T_, g_, i_] := 
  Module[{indices = Append[Delete[Range[Length@Dimensions@T], i], i]},
    Transpose[
     TensorContract[TensorProduct[T, g], {i, Length[indices] + 1}], 
     indices]
  ]

Rcontra = Fold[RaiseIndex[#1, g, #2] &, R, {1, 2, 3, 4}];

TensorContract[TensorProduct[R, Rcontra], {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 7}, {4, 8}}]
```

**Edit:** Explanaion of `RaiseIndex`

Suppose, we want to raise second index $j$ in $R_{ijkl}$:
$$
R^{\ j'}_{i\ kl} = R_{ijkl}g^{jj'}
$$

However, if we just do `R1=TensorContract[R⊗g, {2,5}]`, then the order of the indices will be $i,k,l,j'$. In other words, we need to transpose the tensor to restore the order $i,j',k,l$. The order of transposition is calculated in variable `indices`. It says remove index `i` from sequence `{1,2,...n}` and put it to the end. In the case where $i=2$ and $n=4$: `{1,2,3,4} → {1,3,4,2}`. Now when we do `Transpose[R1, {1,3,4,2}]`, with `R1` having the order of dimensions $i,k,l,j'$, we basically say put dimension $i$ to the 1st place, put dimension $k$ go to the 3rd place, put dimension $l$ to the 4th place and put dimension $j'$ to the 2nd place. Thus, the order of our dimensions (indices) will be $i,j',k,l$.

Since we need to raise all of 4 indices, `Fold` is just a smart way to write this:

```
Rcontra = RaiseIndex[RaiseIndex[RaiseIndex[RaiseIndex[R, g, 1], g, 2], g, 3], g, 4];
```

Please, read help on `Fold` to get further insights.

Comment: Could you explain  the function `RaiseIndex`? It is a bit too difficult for me. And why do you use `Fold`?

Comment: Added explanations

Comment: In addition, we could probably write this: `TensorContract[TensorProduct[R,R,g,g,g,g], {{1,9},{5,10},{2,11},{6,12},{3,13},{7,14},{4,15},{8,16}}]`. However,  it has $4^8=65k$ of components as intermediate tensor product. So, it is easier to raise indices one by one if possible.

Comment: Thanks now I understand.